# ArcusNode Cannot set property '1' of undefined

Tags: node.js, actionscript, rtmfp

My problem is the one discribed in this issue - https://github.com/OpenRTMFP/ArcusNode/issues/5

ArcusNode is dumping the same error for me when I try to stream video to client with RTMFP.

The streamer part is in this repository: https://github.com/JanisGruzis/RtmfpStreamer

The receiver part is in this repository: https://github.com/JanisGruzis/RtmfpVideoPlayer

Those are FDT ActionScript projects. As far as issue tells I should not use stream replication but what is that and how to avoid it in AS? Can I avoid it with NetStream class by configuring it somehow? As you can tell Im quite new to Flash world so maybe Im missing something.

Also, the tutorial I inspired from was the following, but that is probably for Adobe Cirrus. http://old.haxe.org/doc/flash/peer2peer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that ArcusNode is no more maintained (last commit is from 2 years ago). You could try [MonaServer](http://www.monaserver.ovh/) which is a complete open source and lightweight server. It supports each features of RTMFP (object replication, NetStream, NetGroup...).

They are also some samples here : [Mona Samples](http://www.monaserver.ovh/samples.html) (source codes are [here](https://github.com/MonaSolutions/MonaClients))